# Program requires UAC without security manifest

Tags: windows, permissions, uac

So I'm a bit stumped on this one, I was virtualizing Inno Setup with Turbo Studio. When I finished the project I used ExeBuilder like I do on any project that ends up being large enough. When I got my launchers they both required User Account Control to launch, but only when given their original file names. I've never had this happen before so I looked into them, and neither have an internal manifest that has the "requireAdministrator" string. If they don't have a manifest, what is causing them to require UAC when they have certain file names?

**Names that don't require UAC**:

[image: Names that don't require UAC]

**Names that do require UAC**:

[image: Names that do require UAC]

Comment: what are the names of the files?  It could be Installer Detection Technology as detailed here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709628(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Inno Setup Compiler Portable.exe & Inno Setup Documentation.exe

Comment: It isn't Installer Detection, I even checked the target files to see if maybe they had security manifests, and none of them do. Also the documentation exes target is a help .chm file which shouldn't require UAC to be opened.

Comment: @Mr.Mendelli *It isn't Installer Detection* How did you know that? Did you try to disable Installer Detection, reboot and exes still ask for elevation?

Comment: I researched what "Install Detection" was and decided to disable it then reboot. It had no effect. I also tried moving the executables and UAC still persists if I use the file names I want. Unfortunately it looks like I'll just have to use abbreviated names for this project.

Comment: Check the compatibility settings, sometimes Windows ends up setting UAC based on some compatibility routines, and compatibility settings behaves similarily - they are stored in the registry, and based of the filename.

Comment: Sounds good, I was beginning to contemplate this myself. I have also now discovered that if the exes name is "Inno Setu Compiler Portable" the uac prompt is gone. I also got the same issue as before when I compiled Advanced Installer into the same type of virtual application. In this case, when I use "Advanced Installe Portable" as the exe name the UAC prompt is gone as well. I have ruled out that the file names containing "Setup" or "Installer" are the culprates.